# Unable to install Laravel 5.1 via composer, but works on 5.2

Tags: linux, laravel, amazon-ec2

I am having issues creating a new Laravel 5.1 project using composer. Getting bunch of errors.
`composer create-project laravel/laravel test51 "5.1.*"`

I have no problem installing Laravel 5.2 project.

`composer create-project laravel/laravel test52`

Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've actually been running in to this problem lately when spinning up new instances of my Laravel 5.1 project.

From what I can piece together it is causing an issue when running the `php artisan clear-compiled` command as past of the install script.

To get around this I have been running my initial install with the `--no-scripts` option.

It looks like this is available when [creating a project](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#create-project) too, so try running the below when installing Laravel 5.1 initially:

`composer create-project laravel/laravel test51 "5.1.*" --no-scripts`